# Implementing Chat in Website Using Sendbird

Tags: javascript, chat, messaging, sendbird

First I wish to apologize if this is an Inappropriate question but I have a website that I need to implement chat in and I plan on using sendbird. The thing is that I'm not exactly a pro and I've looked at their docs for javascript and seen samples on git but I don't know which to use and even if I do I don't know how to integrate it in my existing project. I would appreciate a gentle nudge in the right direction, a blog post, a video or anything that would help.

Answer (score 1):

No need to! Here you go
https://blog.sendbird.com/sample-website-for-chat-api-and-web-javascript-sdk/

By Git, is this the one you checked out?
https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-JavaScript

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.